# What is the different among IPS and cpu usage?

Tags: android, performance, perf

I try a new type of rnn to decrease power consumption on android. It shows cpu usage dropped from ~10% to ~6%,but IPS increases from 500MIPS to 1000MIPS, on exactly the same device. I tested it several times.
I use android studio profile and simpleperf.

Comment: Sounds like about the same number of instructions run for your workload, but more efficiently (better instruction-level parallelism) so the CPU can "race to sleep" more effectively.

Comment: That makes it more clearer about ips and usage.Actually the new rnn has a lower ops.